# Linux make: Need to rebuild a text file when makefile changes

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

I've inherited a Linux C++ app and makefile.  In the existing makefile, it had code such as the following:

```
APPVER=5.01
REL=B

$(APP): $(OBJS) $(MAKEFILE)
          echo $APPVER > .sw_ver.txt
          echo " " >> .sw_ver.txt
          echo $REL >> .sw_ver.txt
          $(LD) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(APP)
```

At runtime, the app would open this text file and display its version.

In the spirit of Make, rebuilding that `.sw_ver.txt` every time file just felt wrong.  So I broke it up like the following:

```
APPVER=5.01
REL=B

$(APP): $(OBJS) $(MAKEFILE) .sw_ver.txt
          $(LD) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(APP)

.sw_ver.txt: $(MAKEFILE)
          echo $APPVER > .sw_ver.txt
          echo " " >> .sw_ver.txt
          echo $REL >> .sw_ver.txt
```

Steps:

1. `make -B`: it performs the steps, creating the text file and updating the app.
2. do some update the Makefile
3. `make`: here it says there's no need to update the text file and prunes the rule.

I expected it to see the Makefile has changed, and therefore go update the text file. But it doesn't.

I tried adding a dummy file, but it says seems to get pruned.

What I'm trying to do is *if only if* the Makefile has changed (thinking that perhaps `APPVER` or `REL` have changed), then rebuild the `.sw_ver.txt` file.

Do you have any advice?

thanks

===== edit #1

hi, so I tried an alternative, to move the version info out to a file instead of trying to create the file during a make run.  Since I inherited this stuff, I was trying to change as little as possible.

Just for trivia's sake, it would be interesting to know if there is an answer to the original question.

thanks again

file .sw_ver.txt

```
5.01 B
```

Makefile:

```
$(APP): $(OBJS) $(MAKEFILE) .sw_ver.txt
          $(LD) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(APP)

.sw_ver.txt: $(MAKEFILE)
```

===== edit #2

I spoke too soon.  This setup works if any of the `OBJS` are changed, but it does not work if `Makefile` itself is changed.

So, kind strangers... any thoughts?  Thanks

Comment: You haven't given us a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example); are you sure that `MAKEFILE` contains the name of the makefile? (You can check by putting in the line `$(info it contains $(MAKEFILE))` and seeing what it prints.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things to clarify:

1. `MAKEFILE` is not an implicit built-in variable. So if you don't set its value it contains nothing. (You can run `make -p` in a directory *without* a Makefile to see what variables are there. See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html)
2. Based on the reason above, since your `$(MAKEFILE)` is empty, when it expands, the `.sw_ver.txt` becomes a rule *without prerequisites*. Hence if `.sw_ver.txt` already exists, nothing will be done to regenerate it. What you get is actually this (note that your syntax `$APPVER` and `$REL` are actually wrong as well):

   ```
   .sw_ver.txt:                      # $(MAKEFILE) is empty
         echo PPVER > .sw_ver.txt    # $(A) is empty
         echo " " >> .sw_ver.txt
         echo EL >> .sw_ver.txt      # $(R) is empty
   ```

So what you need to do is:

1. Give your `MAKEFILE` variable a value.

   ```
   MAKEFILE := Makefile
   ```
2. Fix your syntax:

   ```
   .sw_ver.txt: $(MAKEFILE)
       echo $(APPVER) > $@
       echo " " >> $@
       echo $(REL) >> $@
   ```

After you do this you should be able to regenerate `.sw_ver.txt` whenever you update your Makefile.

Comment: Thanks... your info led me to find the issue.  My sample was just a small piece of the real Makefile.  I was able to track down the problem with what you had provided.